# Angular CLI - ng e2e throws error

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, angular-cli, angular-e2e

I've just set up a new Angular 4 project using the Angular CLI. Just after creating it, I ran `ng e2e` and the sample end-to-end test executed perfectly. After this, I've added a subfolder inside the `app` folder called `services`, and generated a service inside that folder. Now, when I run `ng e2e`, it errors out with the following error:

> [09:11:56] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file protractor.conf.js
>       [09:11:56] E/configParser - Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Projects\new\test-project\src\app\services\protractor.conf.js

Any idea why this could be happening? I think I might need to prevent the e2e script from looking inside the services folder, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your issue `ng new test-app` then `ng g service services/auth` then `ng e2e` - nothing bakes. I am running `cli 1.3.2`. What is your `cli` version (`ng -v`) ?

Comment: I'm running version 1.2.1 of the cli.

Comment: Do you actually have a protractor config file on that lication `'C:\Projects\new\test-project\src\app\services\protractor.conf.js` ?

Comment: No, I dont. But I shouldn't have to have a protractor.conf.js file in every new folder that I create, should I?

Answer (score 0):

So sounds like you have your `protractor.conf.js` config file is missing on this path `C:\Projects\new\test-project\src\app\services\protractor.co‌​nf.js`. To restore that you can just run `ng new some-app` and copy it over.

To ansewer on your [conmment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955376/angular-cli-ng-e2e-throws-error?noredirect=1#comment78951469_45955376) no, you do not have to create `protractor.conf.js` for each folder there is just one config per app. When you generating a service or component Angular cli generating a `.spec` file but that is different and related to `karma` that is runs with `ng t` or `ng test` or `npm run test`.

Also, if you just starting with Angular, I would recommended to use the latest cli.